# "Probability" of an ECDSA signature

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

The article [Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) in Bitcoin's wiki  talks about signatures having *probabilities* (as in `Signatures are either 73, 72, or 71 bytes long, with probabilities approximately 25%, 50%, and 25% respectively, although sizes even smaller than that are possible with exponentially decreasing probability.`).

What does “probability” mean in this context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the probability that an ECDSA signature (over the Bitcoin curve, secp256k1) will have the corresponding size. In other words, 25% of the secp256k1 ECDSA signatures have 73 bytes, 50% of them have 72 bytes and 25% of them have 71 bytes. Of course, *after* the signature is generated its size is settled and the probability does not apply anymore.

(The reason is that an ECDSA signature is the ASN.1 encoding of a structure with two integers. Each encoded integer requires a bit to indicate the sign, even though in ECDSA they are always positive. Therefore, if the upper bit of the integer is set, then the encoded integer will require a whole byte to store the sign bit since the integers have 256 bits, a multiple of 8. There is a chance of roughly 50% of an integer in the secp256k1 ECDSA signature having the upper bit set, requiring a whole byte for the sign bit, which creates the 25%/50%/25% split over two integers.)

Comment: Thanks -- I totally misunderstood the context.  I think I'll prefix a *Resulting* to the sentence in the wiki.

Comment: Note: the probabilities in the question and answer are approximate, and >0.19% of signatures are less than 71-byte

Comment: Actually the bitcoin format (for transactions) is the ASN.1 encoding of SEQUENCE{INTEGER,INTEGER} _plus_ one added octet for sighash. And the wiki is out of date: since 2014 bitcoin has required so-called 'low-S' signatures (S < n/2, by using -S mod n if needed, which verifies the same because the final check is only on the x-coordinate) to block certain transaction malleability attacks, thus the ASN.1 portion is now ~50% 71, ~50% 70, tiny <70.

Comment: my2cents to just share that someone has thought to use it as a PoW over PoW: https://github.com/VzxPLnHqr/sig-pow